# Localization ios7 without change device's language

Tags: ios, localization, multilingual

I would like to know how to make my application - developed in XCode - multilingual. I read a lot of tutorials about localization but I don't want users to go through Settings->General->International->Language in order to change the application's language. Instead, I want my application to appear on Settings and from there to have an option for change the language (only the application's language). I found an app that do this but I can't find a good tutorial.

Any tutorials or hinds like what is the name of that way of localization it would be very helpful in order to proceed with my app.

### UPDATE

I found that this can be done via custom settings bundle. I want to use localization with storyboard.

I created the settings bundle but I don't know how to proceed.
[image]

### UPDATE

I used this code on the AppDelegate.m file and it works on my mobile device. It changes the interface of my mobile application based on the settings bundle. BUT 1. my mobile application crashes on simulator and 2. with this code when you open the app, then press the middle button of the device, go to settings and change the language, go back to the app THEN the app it restarts! How can I solve this issues?

```
   - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

   {

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSArray* appleLanguages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

NSString* currentLanguage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"language"];

if ([appleLanguages[0] rangeOfString:currentLanguage].location != 0)

{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[currentLanguage] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    exit(0);

}
```

}

Comment: Please could you add some detail about *why* you want to do your localisation through the settings app, instead of using the user's choice of language?

Comment: @Simon my client wants to. The reason is that the application is for a doctor and it has specialized medical words. if users don't have their device language to their mother tongue (most users have their device to english) then is difficult to understand. I don't think it's a good idea to change the language to the device just for one application. Probably users are going to uninstall the application... Anyway that is what my client wants...=/ =/ =/

Comment: @Simon is my reason enough to receive a help?

Comment: Possibly, though I'm not in a position to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same issue for a customer i had : change the setting according to a parameter, without having to restart the app, and without changing the device's name.
I then decided to create my own localization class with some constraints:

- Compatibility with the device language : you can use the device language or any custom language
- Utilisation of the Localizable.strings  -> no need to duplicate the localisation file
- Ability to change the setting for the entire app when changing the parameter : all the labels within the app must be localized when the app language setting is changed. I post a notification when the language is changed, and all the UIViewController suscribe to this notification and configure the labels according to the selected labels.
- You can save the language for further launches of the application with a simple NSUserDefaults parameter.

You can find it here : https://github.com/micazeve/iOS-CustomLocalisator . Any feedback are appreciated, and I'm willing to help if needed.

Comment: After notification is received for language change u manually fetch titles and set them in labels, i wanna do this automatically as is done when language is changed from settings but without restarting [any idea how to achieve this???]